# How can I add validation to an Input field?

Tags: validation, sapui5

Just learning SAP UI5, I have a simple input field like so:

**app.xml**

```
<Input
    placeholder="Please enter 10 digit number"
    value=""
/Input>
```

I'm trying to understand how I can add a validation on the input field that does the following:

-Accepts a number of 10 digits or more

So far, what I understand, this can be setup in the following way:

```
<Input value=”{

    path : ‘/userName’,
    type : ‘sap.ui.model.type.Integer’,
    constraints : {
        minLength : 10
    }
}
```

Where I'm getting confused:

The input field is meant to act as a search bar, therefore I don't need to introduce databinding (search bar should not have an initial value) where I have to configure a path. Can someone explain to me how I can add validation without setting a 'Path'?

Comment: To the contrary, I would still use databinding, especially with a search field :-)
If you bind it to a local JSON model, you can then use the model data, instead of referring to a control's value (which, in true MVC fashion, should not happen anyway)

Answer (score 6):

If you check the documentation for [`Input`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input), you'll see that the control has the event `liveChange`. Furthermore, you can also use the validators to give immediate feedback to the users.

Let's see an example.

View:

```xml
<Input liveChange = "onLiveChange" />
```

Controller:

```js
onLiveChange(oEvent) {
    let newValue = oEvent.getParameter("newValue");

    //you can also use None, or just remove this line
    this.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Success); 

    if(/* your error condition */)
        this.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
    }
}
```

When "your condition" is true, the whole input will change its border.

Anyway, if you want to use a model, you could try to create a local JSON-model, and try to bind it to the input with the constraint. But in this case, I would just go with the first solution.