# How to filter odata service with mutiple filter input values from Filterbar control & bind the filtered result set to Table

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I need to filter the odata service with multiple filter items and bind result set to table. This whole action will take place on click of search button. Below is my Onsearch event code which is failing in read function and not returning a result and not able to bind it to table. Can anyone please me help on this?

#### Controller Code

```js
onFinalFilter: function (oEvent) {

debugger; 
var oPlant = this.getView().byId("plant").getValue();

var oName1 = this.getView().byId("name1").getValue();

var oName2 = this.getView().byId("name2").getValue();

var oState = this.getView().byId("State").getValue();

var oCity = this.getView().byId("city").getValue();

var oZip = this.getView().byId("zip").getValue();

var oCompanyCode = this.getView().byId("companyCode").getValue();

var p = new Filter("WERKS", FilterOperator.EQ, oPlant);

var n1 = new Filter("NAME1", FilterOperator.EQ, oName1);

var n2 = new Filter("NAME2", FilterOperator.EQ, oName2);

var s = new Filter("STATE", FilterOperator.EQ, oState);

var c = new Filter("CITY", FilterOperator.EQ, oCity);

var cc = new Filter("BUKRS", FilterOperator.EQ, oCompanyCode);

var zip = new Filter("PSTCODE", FilterOperator.EQ, oZip);

var finalFilter = new Filter({filters:[p,n1,n2,c,s,zip,cc], and:true});

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSM_PLANTSRCH_SRV/"); sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

var oModel2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

oModel.read("/PLANTSRCHSet", {

filters: finalFilter, 

success: function (oData, oResponse)

{ var data = oData; oModel2.setData(data); this.getView().byId("table1").setModel(oModel2, "key2"); },

error: function (oError) { //alert("error"); } });

}
```

#### View

[image: view]

#### Console Log

[image: Console Log:]

#### Filterbar Fragment

[image: Filterbar Fragment]

Answer (score -1):

1.View.xml

```
    <fb:FilterGroupItem  name="Name of the Property" label="Company">
                    <fb:control>
                        <Input type="Text"/>
                    </fb:control>               
                </fb:FilterGroupItem>
```

- The name should be the corresponding property of your EntitySet of your oData Service

2. Controller.js - prepare your filter

```js
        _search: function (oEvt) {
            // All your filters of the filterbar
            var aSelectionSet = oEvt.getParameter("selectionSet");
            //Loop through them all
            var aFilters = aSelectionSet.reduce(function (aResult, oControl) {
                //Check via oControl.getValue() || oControl.getSelectedKey() || oControl.getMetadata().getName() what to do
                if (oControl.getValue()) { //sap.m.Input - single filter
                    aResult.push(new Filter({
                        path: oControl.getName(),
                        operator: FilterOperator.EQ,
                        value1: oControl.getValue()
                    }));
                } else if (oControl.getMetadata().getName() === "sap.m.MultiInput") { // sap.m.MultiInput - multiple Filter
                    var aTokens = oControl.getTokens();
                    var aTokenFilter = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < aTokens.length; i++) {
                        aTokenFilter.push(new Filter({
                            path: oControl.getName(),
                            operator: FilterOperator.EQ,
                            value1: aTokens[i].getProperty("key")
                        }));
                    }
                    if (aTokenFilter.length > 0) {
                        aResult.push(new Filter({
                            filters: aTokenFilter,
                            and: false
                        }));
                    }
                }
                return aResult;
            }, []);
            if (aFilters.length > 0) {
                this._filterTable(new Filter({
                    filters: aFilters,
                    and: true
                }));
            } else {
                this._filterTable();
            }
        },
```

- There's no logic for **sap.m.ComboBox** yet

3. Controller.js - filter

```
        _filterTable: function (oFilter) {
        this._oTable.getBinding("items").filter(oFilter);
        }
```

[Example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.valuehelpdialog.filterbar/code/ValueHelpDialogFilterbar.controller.js)

Comment: thank you for response . I also need to put validation for the filterbar input fileds. As above code aResult holding all the filters , how can I put the validation for the individual values like if name , city fileds based on the input value need to do the vlaidation check and if pass then will push to filter. If you can help in this will be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can validate pre filtering. [-->How can i add validation to an input field<--](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186455/how-can-i-add-validation-to-an-input-field).  in the `_search` method you can check the validation via `oControl.getValueState()`. Like @Boghyon Hoffmann mentioned, feel free to update your Question with an CodeSnippet and more specific question

Comment: initially tried to fetch filtergroupitems value but was not able to figure out to pass the filters parameter to service.tried different approach now, but it's failing too. Have updated the questio as well. Previous Code  was: -var oJsonData = [];
   var oItems = oEvent.getSource().getFilterGroupItems();
   for (var i = 0; i < oItems.length; i++) { 
    
    var oControl = oEvent.getSource().determineControlByFilterItem(oItems[i]);
    if (oControl) {
     oControl.getValue();
     oJsonData.push(oControl.getValue());
    }
   return oJsonData;